# Dashboard: Inheriting Permission in Document Library for Folder/Files

Tags: 2013, permissions, folder, file, dashboard

We have a document library with a complex permission structure on folders and files. Is there a possibility to get a report to see or manage the permission in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: I found no Reports or something else

Comment: Have you considered using PowerShell?

Comment: I have no rights for it